# Regular Expression repetition of class

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to figure out a regular expression for the following:

```
<tr class="A">.*</tr><tr class="(B|C)">.*</tr>
```

Now The second tr class will repeat an unknown number of times, with something unknown in between repetitions, but simply putting it in parentheses and added a plus doesn't work.

Here's the PHP code that didn't work:

```
$pattern = '/<tr\ class=\"A\">.*(<tr\ class=\"(B|C)\">.*<\/tr>.*)+/';
preg_match_all($pattern,$playerHtml,$scores);
```

But it only returns the first

Here's an example of something that should match:

```
<tr class="A">blah</tr>blah
<tr class="B">blah</tr>blah
<tr class="B">blah</tr>blah
<tr class="C">blah</tr>
```

This only matches blahblahblah

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are trying to match?

Comment: Yeah sure.  I'm trying to match something like this:
<tr class="A">blah</tr><tr class="B">blah</tr>blah<tr class="B">blah</tr>blah<tr class="C">blah</tr>

Comment: You want to capture all consecutive tr elements that have a class attribute?

Comment: No, I want to capture all sets where it's an A class followed by any number of B and C classes.

Comment: I had problems with outputting random TR elements, but I think I got it.  Check my answer.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular example, this regex will do:

```
/<tr class="A">.*?<\/tr>.*\n?(<tr class="[BC]">.*?<\/tr>.*\n?)+/
```

Hope you can tweak it if need be.  See the codepad demo [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QUaUOF).

I needed to include `\n` newline characters for it to work.

Because they are TR elements outside of TABLE elements, I had a hard time seeing the result of the preg_match_all function (because my browser immediately stripped the random TR elements).  You may have had similar problems.  I used [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) in the demo to output the regex match.

**Also**, it's improper to have text between two TR elements:

`<tr></tr>blah<tr></tr>`

So you should be careful about doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 <tr class="A">.*</tr><tr class="((B|C)\s*)+">.*</tr>
```

`+` indicates one or more times and `*` indicates 0 or more times. Also `\s` inidcates a white space.

`((B|C)\s*)+` means there will be one or more blocks of `(B|C)\s*`

`(B|C)\s*` means there will be a string starts with `B` or `C` then some whitespaces may be followed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it, since I'm on my phone, but what do you get in $scores with this pattern?

```
<tr class="A">.*</tr><tr class="((B)|(C)|[^"]+)+">.*</tr>
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think my original question was very clear.  Check the example of what should match.

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match_all` will look for your *whole* pattern multiple times.

As it's found only once (I assume because the start is in `$playerHtml` only once), you only get one match.

Instead, first look for your whole pattern and extract the part you're interested in, then continue with that segment:

```
$pattern = '/<tr\ class=\"A\">.*(<tr\ class=\"(B|C)\">.*<\/tr>.*)+/';
$r = preg_match($pattern, $playerHtml, $matches);
if (FALSE === $r) throw new Exception('Regex failed.');

list(,$scoreHtml) = $matches;

$r = preg_match_all('/(<tr\ class=\"(B|C)\">.*<\/tr>.*)/', $scoreHtml, $scores);
if (FALSE === $r) throw new Exception('Regex failed.');
```

This code is quickly written and will most certainly not work, it's just for illustrating that you need to do multiple steps.

However, if you're using a HTML parser instead of regular expressions, I bet it's much more quickier to obtain the values you're after with some little xpath query:

```
//tr[@class="B" or @class="C"]
```

This selects all `<tr>` elements with the classes you look for. Much easier.